# How to implement multithreading - if possible - on this piece of code?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am building a Finite Element Analysis library in C#. In each structure I am to analyze, there is a need to perform several calculations on element level and bring the results together on a structure level. All these calculations take quite a woke when there are many elements.

For example, there is the calculation of element stiffness matrices and the assembly of the same into the global stiffness matrix.

Is there a way to make the process take advantage of threading?

```
public class FEStructure
{
    public List<Element> elements = new List<Element>;
    public Matrix K;

    Struct()
    {
        // Do some stuff not relevant here
    }

    public void CalcK()
    {
        // Create a Global stiffness matrix (n x n)
        K = new DenseMatrix(SizeK());

        // Process all elements - can it be threaded?
        foreach (Element e in elements)
        {
            // Get the element stiffness matrix  and assemble it into K
            Matrix Ke = e.CalcKe();
            Assemble(Ke);
        }
    }

    public void Assemble(Matrix Ke)
    {
        // Assembles Ke into K using the element topology
        // and lot of fields and methods left out. Code
        // operates on K using syntax similar to:
        K[i, j] = Ke[k, l];
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

The calculation of the element matrices through `e.CalcKe()` is an independent calculation and can be performed in any order.

Comment: Is it possible to calculate each `Element e` separately or do they require being calculated in order? If they are unrelated to each other and don't rely on some sort of progressive state, you might get away with `Parallel.ForEach`.

Comment: Is it the `e.CalcKe();` that takes so long?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth, there is no need for a specific calculation order.

Comment: @corn3lius I do not know if it is e.CalcKe() or Assemble() that consumes the most time, all I know is that the entire process takes to long when working with thousands of elements. Furthermore, this is just a piece of the entire code and there are several similar processes that I'd like to cut down processing time on.

Comment: I would also avoid naming the class `Struct` to avoid confusion with the `struct` keyword.

Comment: @BryanCrosby Good point. Will do as soon as I come up with a suitable name :)

Comment: I would recommend you profile the code before trying to optimize it (try a tool like ANTS Performance Profiler or the similar one from JetBrains that I cannot remember the name of now). Perhaps threading is not the approach that will yield the best performance benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to parellize the for each loop on threads easily using Parallel.ForEach.

You will just need to ensure that the assignments into the matrix is thread-safe, and that the individual calculations does not depend on being done in order.

Comment: Thank you. How do I ensure that the assignments are thread-safe? Can you point me to a good example?

Comment: It depends on the implementation of the Matrix class. Is the [i,j] unique for elements ? Would assigning to two different indexes at the same time on different threads be a problem ? Is the storage pre-allocated, or does it need to grow ? Etc, etc.

Comment: The Matrix class is part of the [Math.NET Numerics library](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/) and as far as I know, the Matrix object is just holding a Double array[][] in which data is stored and then the class provides linear algebraic operations through various methods. If you can assign several positions in a array, I guess it is possible as well in the Matrix object. Some elements will be assembled into the same position [i, j] in the global matrix K, but not all. The storage is preallocated through `K = new DenseMatrix(SizeK())`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Parallel.ForEach(elements, e =>
{
     var eResult = e.CalcKe(); 
     AggregateResults(eResult);
}

void AggregateResults(Matix r)
{
    lock(denseMatrix)
        denseMatix[a,b] = r[k,l];
}
```